# How long does Rhythmbox keep podcast? How do I schedule a automatic cleanup?

Tags: rhythmbox

I guess my question is fairly straight forward: How long does Rhythmbox keep podcast? How do I schedule a automatic cleanup?

I don't seem to see any way to set a limit in how many days a podcast is kept before auto delete.

Using: 14.10 with gnome shell.